# Embed a ViewController into a AVPlayerController as an Overlay

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

**My Issue**: I'm trying to embed a ViewController (with an image and a button) into a an AVPlayerController, similar to the way YouTube is showing ads on their videos (on the bottom of the video, and will stay there).

**My Approach**: I have the following test code

```swift
let AVPC = AVPlayerViewController()
            avpc!.player = self.contentPlayer
            avpc!.view.frame = f
            self.addChild(avpc!)
let adView = UIView()
adView.frame = CGRect(x: ??, y: ??, width: 300, height: 70)
AVPC.contentOverlayView.addSubview(adView)
```

**Result**: My view will calculate correctly the size of my AVPlayerController when it's minimized. But, when I go into full screen view it will either get out of bounds or not work at all.

**Mock**
[image]

Comment: You need to set auto layout for `adView` to change with your player size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look [autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html), and there are some tools for auto layout with less code, like [SnapKit](http://snapkit.io)

Here is a sample way to handle it without any library.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let adView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }()

    func playVideo() {
        let videoURL = URL(string: "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player
        playerViewController.contentOverlayView?.addSubview(adView)

        adView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        adView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        adView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: adView.superview!.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        adView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: adView.superview!.leadingAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
        adView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: adView.superview!.trailingAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true

        self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
            playerViewController.player!.play()
        }
    }
}
```

[image] [image]